# Ctrl + Alt + Del with a mac keyboard

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard

I have a Windows 7 computer with which I use an Apple keyboard. At each login, I am prompted to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> before entering my password.

Because the Mac keyboard doesn't seem to have a <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, I have so far resorted to the "on-screen" virtual keyboard. This is quite annoying and I wondered if there is a better approach.

By the way, what is the point of this stupid <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> thing?

Comment: This requirement can be disabled via Group Policies (`gpedit.msc`).

Comment: What Apple keyboard doesn't have a delete key? Anyway, try the numeric keypad (period/decimal with num lock off - if it doesn't have num lock, try and see if one of the 'non-PC' keys on the numeric keypad, clear and =, are mapped to numlock by default.)

Comment: *> The Mac keyboard doesn't seem to have a Del key*   `o.O`   What kind of keyboard does not have a delete key? Can you post a photo of it?   I just plugged an [old Mac SE keyboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bQyGd.jpg) into a 64-bit Windows 7 laptop and it worked just fine using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` (`Option` has *alt* above it and [`del` has a polygon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yz55r.png) (in fact, I’m typing this whole comment on it).   You can also press [`Fn`+`BS`](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/495913?start=0&tstart=0), for `Del`, but that’s for Macbooks, not separate keyboards.

Comment: @Randomblue it's a feature for accessing security options [task manager], [power options] if something goes wrong. For the iMac, we use the power button instead of CTRL + ALT + DEL, because a reboot is SOO much better than just pressing 3 keys. (Sarcasm included). But please, don't call things you don't know about stupid. I'm pretty sure the Americans didn't call pizza disgusting before knowing how it tasted. [No offense]

Comment: ASCII has both backspace (decimal 8) and delete (decimal 127).  My mac keyboard (on an old PowerBook) has a key labelled "delete", but I believe it sends the equivalent of a "Backspace".  Anyway, to make a long story short, on my powerbook at least pressing the keys labelled "fn", "control" "alt/option" and "delete" at the same time seems to generate the equivalent of control-alt-delete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows is designed so that, unless system security is already compromised in some other way, only the Winlogon process, a trusted system process, can receive notification of the [C-A-D key combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete#DOS-based_Windows)

You could probably [remap the keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) , try ctrl alt fn-delete (the easiest potential solution) or simply turn off the need to use the [three fingered salute to log on](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308226)

Comment: which one worked? ;p

Comment: I simply turned off the three fingered salute. :)

Comment: also works quite well when using Remote Desktop from a Mac to a PC for force-quitting remote PC programs when you forget that the program to do this is called 'Task Manager'

Comment: the "remap the keyboard" link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the [Apple Wireless Keyboard Helper](http://applewirelesskbrd.codeplex.com/), it maps Mac keys combos to windows keypresses.

> - <kbd>F3</kbd>: Printscreen
> - <kbd>F4</kbd>: Task Manager
> - <kbd>F7</kbd> - <kbd>F9</kbd>: iTunes Control
> - <kbd>F10</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>: System volume Control
> - <kbd>Eject</kbd>: Toggles Fkeys/Functions
> - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F key</kbd>: Triggers function (useful when in F keys mode)
> - <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> = Del

Comment: Good try, but didn't work. Thanks for the other shortcuts though.

Comment: I use ctrl+alt+fn+backspace from my mbp keyboard

Answer (score 6):

When using a Mac keyboard attached to a PC, the Mac keyboard key I use for the PC <kbd>Del</kbd> key is the <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> key combination.

This works with <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>option (alt)</kbd> to form a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.

Using the Mac's <kbd>delete</kbd>, which is equivalent to the PC's <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, does not work for me. I don't need to use <kbd>⇧</kbd> with <kbd>option (alt)</kbd>.

Comment: this actually worked, it should be the selected answer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  Every combination failed me.  In full disclosure, I am not using a wireless bluetooth keyboard.  I am using a usb keyboard with the numeric keypad on the right.  After failing with all the combos above, I made sure the num lock was off.  I used control (not the command key, just regular control key), option (aka alt with no fn key combo), and the "." from the keypad.  No lie, that is what I used.  Control + option + .

Comment: thanks!  I just set up an incredibly ancient Mac keyboard -- the 1999 USB one w/ transparent housing -- USB -- to my Win laptop, and CTRL-ALT-NumericPad"."  worked!   Since this KB doesn't even have a <FN> key, this was the only way.

Comment: It works!! Thanks. I'm using a Bluetooth magic keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

I had the scenario of working on my Mac, but was forced to remotely log into a Windows VM.

Windows would automatically lock the screen after several minutes of inactivity and the usual

> Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete to Unlock!

message would appear.

The key combinations on my Mac keyboard - that's equivalent to that Window's counterpart - for me was pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Thats funny, none of my Macs or my Apple keyboards have a delete key

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> then go to start and type `netplwiz` open it and hit advanced then uncheck Require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> at login.Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

For my MAC, Fn+Control+Option+Delete works for VMWare Horizon Client running a Windows desktop. The combination will not work if the Command key is used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remap your <kbd>Del</kbd> key to something. You can use [Input Remapper](http://www.olofsson.info/index.html?inputremapper.html) to do that. It will even try to detect you mac keyboard and make some of the setting for you.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac keyboard, I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> which says Delete.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just download and install this software:
http://ahkscript.org/
It will enable you to remap your keyboard buttons.
and run the script Iv'e created to replace the backslash button need the enter key with delete key (see picture attached)

[Link to the script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1FRh4A2RcMZU1YzWWk3ZFE4SzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Enjoy

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same problem and the best solution I found is to use Apple's BootCamp which provides the drivers for Apple Keyboard.

Go to apple support page, download BootCamp, extract and install  AppleKeyboard only ([instructions here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D31uzS1Szek)), and then fn key works on windows.

One can now use fn-BackSpace to get the windows-like del, like it is done on a mac. Together you get all the predefined function keys on the mac keyboard working on windows (like volume control, brightness control, etc)

Comment: Thank you for you contribution, but whilst this may potentially answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential information here, and provide the link for reference. Please **edit your answer** to include that information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an old transparent Mac keyboard of an original Bondi Blue iMac which has no Fn key (I like the touch of it!) on a Windows PC running Win 10, I find that the key combination of Control-ALT-Numeric keypad .    (numeric keypad decimal or dot key) works and will bring up the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Because any keyboards have 2 CTRL and ALT keys, I manage to use like this: CTRL (left) + ALT (right) + Del (like normal keyboards).

Answer (score 0):

I use an Apple magic keyboard with number keypad on a PC.
Control, Option and Decimal (on numeric keypad portion) executes a Ctrl - Alt - Del on my PC. Hope its helpful here.

TC