# How can I Ctrl + Alt + Delete on Win 10 using a Mac keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, mac

My company has our laptops set up to use Ctrl + Alt + Delete to allow us to type in our password to log on.

I want to be able to use a Mac keyboard with my Windows 10. But no matter what combination I use in either of the below links, I can't find the combination for Ctrl Alt Delete.

[Ctrl + Alt + Del with a mac keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/347350/ctrl-alt-del-with-a-mac-keyboard)

https://www.dell.com/community/vWorkspace/How-to-unlock-cltr-alt-end-on-Apple-MAC/td-p/4306026

I've tried this with two different mac keyboards, both of them not having num pads, so no dedicated delete key.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Try Cmd/opt/backspace & Fn/Cmd/opt/backspace. if no joy repeat with Ctrl instead of Cmd. [Fn/Backspace emulates the forward delete key on Mac, idk how Win is going to interpret that]

Comment: @Tetsujin None work, I've tried all these already.

Comment: Use a Windows keyboard then ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Macs, the Command key is physically located where our fingers are used to the Alt key location, at least in the US.  But, it's the Option key that sends the same keycode.  So... you *should* be able to use Ctrl-Opt-Delete, except I'm not 100% sure that the Mac's delete key corresponds to the Windows one.

Since you want to use your Mac keyboard permanently with a PC (which is exactly what I do, using a USB switch to go between the Mac and PC), you REALLY should download Keytweak for Windows (available at https://keytweak.en.softonic.com/ and many other popular download sites), run it and map your Mac keys.  Here's a pic of my mapping to get you started, although you can't see a couple others that I have mapped (UI won't scroll), but you'll get the idea.
[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to have two bindings for the same key? So keep delete on the original key but also make F5 be delete too?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can, because it's intercepting the key presses and passing along what ever keycodes you want, so you should be able to set 2 keys to send the same keycode.  I think the mapping is done with the key as the "key", if you understand software dictionaries/hashes, so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question was ever answered, but I solved the issue on my magic keyboard.  I discovered a second delete button -- not the larger delete button that has the word "delete" (next to the + button), but instead the delete button to the left of the "end" button and directly beneath the fn button. This second delete button has a little x on it as well.  I'd never seen it before but just stumbled on it.  Control-option-little delete button.

Take away: I hit this particular CTRL-ALT-DELETE combination and it successfully took me to my work windows login page.  Hopefully this helps someone who's been struggling with Google or trying different combinations involving the apple command button, etc.

Comment: This second delete button that you have just discovered is the *actual* `DEL` key used in the usual [`CTRL-ALT-DEL key combination`](https://i.insider.com/5f062577191824608056e9d2), the larger key is the `backspace` key.

Answer (score 1):

Long time Mac user here & I know this is an old post, but...
What Tom Morris said above is correct on a full-size Mac keyboard. On a TKL (ten keyless) Mac keyboard there is only one delete key. That delete key is really just backspace and fn + delete is actually delete.

Windows CTRL = Mac CTRL

Windows ALT  = Mac Option

Windows DEL  = Mac FN + Delete

Windows Key  = Mac CMD

[image of keys discussed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aYaC.png)

So in order to do CTRL + ALT + DEL for Windows on a Mac keyboard you have to do CTRL + Option + FN + Delete. Take into consideration that keyboards that can control multiple devices at one time (Logitech MX Keys, Satechi, etc.) may have the keys mapped differently but may give you the option to remap them.

Answer (score 0):

If on an iPad click the options button in the middle of the screen (looks like two squares). Click the keyboard option and Control Alt Delete will appear as options - click on all three and windows should unlock.

Answer (score 0):

This is even easier -
Bring up the Onscreen Keyboard in Windows 10

Select Cntrl+Alt on the Mac Keyboard and then Select Delete using your mouse and the onsreen Keyboard

Done

Answer (score 0):

If anybody finds this looking for a way to Ctrl+Alt+Del on a Mac in Windows via Citrix, there's a menu item in Citrix Viewer for Mac: Devices/Keyboard/Send Ctrl+Alt+Del