# Ctrl + Alt + Del using "Apple Magic Keyboard 2 with keypad" on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, mac

There is a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/347350/ctrl-alt-del-with-a-mac-keyboard) already, but it relates basically to MAC keyboard.
And is quite old.

Since it does not talk about [Apple Magic Keyboard 2 with keypad](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MRMH2LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-space-gray), and it looks to be having a separate `delete`
key in the latest iteration, so is it still a problem to issue `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Delete` on this keyboard on windows?
I plan to use this with windows/linux OS only, so was eager to know if there are still major issues on these OS that are unsolved, and found these kinds of workarounds all the place on the internet.

Please let me know if someone has this keyboard already and such workarounds are still needed or not.
This will help me decide if its worth to hold on to this $130 keyboard or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the linked question is that a short [laptop-style] keyboard has a backspace but not a delete key. You have to use Fn to change backspace to delete.

Extended keyboards have a separate delete key, so there should be no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so any idea, what buttons are needed to effect ctrl + alt + delete? Does control key on magic keyboard works similar to CTRL key on windows keyboards? because for ctrl+c[copy shortcut] i guess we need to press command + c on a magic keyboard [as per details posted on the internet] ?

Comment: Ctr;/alt/del is just that, same as on a Win keyboard. The Command key, if used on a Windows PC, acts as the Windows Key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to try control + option + delete on a Mac keyboard. This will bring up the option to change password, open task manager, etc on a Windows computer...for example if using RDP to access a server.

Comment: RDP specifically uses non-standard key combinations in order not to conflict with the local system specific key combinations. Also note that this question has been answered with a good answer that solved OPs problem.